# I'm having trouble accessing modules from standard packages that i have imported

Tags: python, package

I can't access modules in packages i have imported using the attribute method unless i use the * method. This issue has now started affecting the classes i import into the workspace. Initially with the packages atleast there is a work around but now with the classes, i cant access their attributes.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages. Nothing's changed

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you saying you can use `from module import *` but you can't use `import module`?

Comment: I have noticed that the issue with the classes was as a result of poor programming choices.  For example in Tkinter, the issue was that i was packing a method in the same instance i had defined it and therefore performing manipulations at later stages was raising the errors.

Comment: What does that have to do with importing modules?

Comment: @Barmar if i use the import package method, i will only get access to few of the modules in the package. It is only when i use from package import * that all modules are imported

Comment: You need to post a [mre] and the error you're getting.